# Atom legend in VESTA

Tags: software, visualization-software, vesta

Is it possible to to display the atom legend in VESTA and export the structure including the legend as a vector/raster image?

I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vesta-discuss/xjVzlnFw6Zo) discussion from 2013 requesting this feature. Has it been added?

Comment: I'm pretty certain the answer is no.

Comment: That's unfortunate for a cool software like vesta.

Comment: If you have access to [CrystalMaker](http://crystalmaker.com/), that is one program where this can readily be done.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible in VESTA at this time.